# How to rewrite an element's attribute value using the current attribute value?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I've got an almost working XSLT sample, but for some reason it adds the attribute to the parent instead of rewriting the node I am trying to rewrite.

#### Input XML

```xml
<Include xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="WEBFOLDER">
            <Directory Id="dirA82847423D2E0E6780E69FEDB5941AC0" Name="web">
                <Component Id="cmpADE52C2B19915F5AFB7C41166996B6C5" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil83688EC53AE556DE24B5F5444F16F6BE" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SolutionDir)\Company.PCR.Blazor.dll" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Include>
```

#### My XSL (transformation)

```xml
<!-- patch relative paths -->
<xsl:template match="wix:File">
    <xsl:attribute name="Source">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(self::node()/@Source,0,19), '..\artifacts\msi\web\', substring(self::node()/@Source, 20))"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

#### Actual output (currently transformed)

```xml
<Include xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
   <Fragment>
      <DirectoryRef Id="WEBFOLDER">
         <Directory Id="dirA82847423D2E0E6780E69FEDB5941AC0" Name="web">
            <Component Id="cmpADE52C2B19915F5AFB7C41166996B6C5" Guid="*" Source="$(var.SolutionDir)..\artifacts\msi\web\Company.PCR.Blazor.dll"/>
         </Directory>
      </DirectoryRef>
   </Fragment>
</Include>
```

#### Expected XML output (transformed):

```xml
<Include xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="WEBFOLDER">
            <Directory Id="dirA82847423D2E0E6780E69FEDB5941AC0" Name="web">
                <Component Id="cmpADE52C2B19915F5AFB7C41166996B6C5" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil83688EC53AE556DE24B5F5444F16F6BE" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SolutionDir)..\artifacts\msi\web\Company.PCR.Blazor.dll" />
                </Component>
         </Directory>
      </DirectoryRef>
   </Fragment>
</Include>
```

Can you explain why my `match="wix:File"` applies its attribute change to its parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify the `Source` attribute, then why not make the template match the `Source` attribute?

```
<xsl:template match="wix:File/@Source">
    <xsl:attribute name="Source">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 1, 18), '..\artifacts\msi\web\', substring(., 20))"/>
    </xsl:attribute>        
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Because today is my first day with xslt actually. Thanks for your answer

Comment: ⚠️ The more restrictive matching means, that source-attribute is only updated if exists, but not added if it is missing on respective XML-element.

Comment: Do you want it to be added if it's missing? And if so, what should it contain (given that currently you're just inserting a substring into the existing value)?

Comment: No, I don't want it to be added (defaulting). That clarification is up to OP. I just wanted to add the trade-off when restricting a match. The comment was only for other visitors with similar use-cases.

Comment: My suggested edit (you rolled back) intended to improve your answer by explaining your patch. Because visitors could be not familiar with XPath's attribute notation, like OP confessed too. Didn't want to criticize your answer.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Your answer perfectly answered my question. Referencing the current selector by "." was helpful too. I know that from xaml